# color right column background and override bootstrap container

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I wanna set the second col background color. and i want it to stretch to the
side of the screen, override the container thats it's in. anyone know how i can do this?

```
<div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">

            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">

            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Like shown on this image
[image: sample of design]
<sub>(source: [image-share.com](https://www.image-share.com/upload/3032/255m.jpg))</sub>

As always, thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

For the background color, I'd set a `style` or a `css class`:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6" style="background-color:red">

</div>
```

It's not a good practice in css to make that div override a div it's contained at. If you'd like it to be over the other div, i'd just use `z-index`.

read more [here.](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

**EDIT**: [Snippet dog](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U1ei5rwO7ZI) to your request.

```html
<div class="container" style="left:400; background-color:blue;opacity:0.8;z-index:-1;">
  <h1> here the container starts</h1>
          <div class="row" style="z-index:0;"> <!-- the row is in front of the container, which allows elements to flow past the edge of it-->
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6" style="background-color:green;opacity:0.8; width:100px; height:200px;">
            This div is fully contained, since you didn't apply z index & left to it. It's on the left because you didn't add the float trait to it.
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6" style="background-color:red;opacity:0.8;left:0; z-index:1;width:100px; height:200px; float:right;">
            Here the overfolowing div starts.<br> notice how it's partially out of the container.
            </div>
        </div>
  <h1> here the container ends</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: If i make it over a other div with z-index. i need to set a position right? Curse if i set a background color on the div with the col right now, it won't go out of the container. an i really need it to do this.

Comment: @DaCh It can. Set the position the way you want, maybe even take the second div out of the first and set an `opacity` trait (to 0.8, let's say) - this way you'll see how they override each other.

Comment: @DaCh If you'd like me to add a snippet as an example, just ask for it and I will (:

Comment: just wondering how this will work responsive. but i would like a snippet very much. thank you :)

Comment: @Dach Take a look at my edit. is this what you wanted?

Comment: @DaCh PS - responsive is prefectly valid in this case too. `z-index` doesn't have to be responsive since it's just an indicator to who becomes before who, and the `left` trait is a responsive 0 :) float is modify-able.

Comment: first. thanks for the music. made my day. but im afraid that this do not fix my problem. it's not going over the bootstrap container, even when i tried your code.

Comment: @DaCh Heh, sure - Anyhow, add the boostrap code for all these classes and then I can try to mess around with it. One example of something which can interrupt this is `position:relative` - if it's set in the container/row/col, for example, it could make the div go left relative to the container rather than the page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87390/discussion-between-a-abramov-and-dach).

Answer (score 1):

With CSS

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    #a {
        background: red;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
     }
 }
```

this would give you the effect you want *if the 2nd div taller than the first div*

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6" id="a">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-push-6">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice the extra `col-md-push-6` on the 2nd div.

Comment: @Dipak I don't understand what's wrong with their answer, as long as the divs are not on the same `z-index` and are not related. Please elaborate.

Comment: @Dipak - I'm afraid I'm missing something. Would this cause any problems with the layout? I thought left:0 would be a good way to stretch it over the container to the left. Cheers!

Comment: @A.Abramov (1), when you use Bootstrap the classes that begin with 'col-' are already columns, meaning they don't need to be floated, or made inline elements. (2), the CSS property 'poistion: absolute' removes the element from DOM flow and puts it as a individual element (relative to body), why do you do that? (3) Please stop answering the questions you are not aware of the actual use of that technology. potatopeelings, please tell me why you used the position and left property? (4) Don't post answers for reputations

Comment: @Dipak - OP wants to "stretch to the side of the screen, *override* the container". Wouldn't that be reasonable cause to actually set position: absolute. Btw, you didn't have to delete your earlier comment. It's all feedback :-). I would definitely want to know if I've made a mistake. Cheers!

Comment: @Dipak I understand, yet that is fully overrideable. Although thats not the best practice for usage of bootstrap, it's perfectly valid if you ask me. OP clearly stated he wanted the column div stuck at the side of the screen.

Comment: @potatopeelings Thanks for taking the feedback positively. Even in that case, the solution you provided will break the UI, or will create more issues than expected. Have you tried such example?

Comment: @potatopeelings I tried your code. but this just make a lot of problem. like the content under vil move up curse its overlapping.

Comment: @Dipak - I tried a relatively simple test. It will definitely need a few more tweaks to get it working correctly - but those tweaks depend on the relative size of the first 2 divs, and what OP wants to do on small screens (for instance the #a positioning rule would need media query, but I'm not sure what it should be unless OP wants to do on small screens given that it's a cleaned up example just to illustrate the problem). I'm pretty sure OP won't upvote or accept unless he / she tries it out :-)

Comment: @DaCh - I assume you are talking about the content from the .row below. You're right that this would creep up when the 2nd div above is shorter than the first div (I just edited the answer to indicate this and also added a media query for xs). This would be easy to fix *if* you know the height of the 1st div. However if you don't, the above solution would unfortunately not work and you'll want to look at other answers and throw tomatoes at this one. Cheers!

Comment: @potatopeelings i would never throw tomatoes after a answer to a problem i have, when people have been so kind to help me :)